# If I use EXPOSE $PORT in a Dockerfile, can I un-expose the port it when I use `docker run`?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm working on a Dockerfile for a web app that will use an [nginx-proxy](https://hub.docker.com/r/jwilder/nginx-proxy/) container. It's also got a CLI for doing app domain stuff (creating/modifying db, running cleanup jobs, etc.)

In 99% of cases, when I boot a container, I want to use the webapp. I've got an `EXPOSE 3000` in the Dockerfile and that works perfectly well for NGINX-proxy. Nginx-proxy uses [docker-gen](https://github.com/jwilder/docker-gen), which listens for docker's `start` and `stop` events and re-builds the NGINX config based on exposed ports.

The problem comes when I want to run a CLI-based container. I *don't* want to `EXPOSE 3000`. I want to un-expose port 3000, so NGINX-proxy doesn't change the NGINX configs.

Is this possible from `docker run`? Reading the docs didn't give any clarity, and trying `docker run -p ''` didn't do work (I got a `docker: No port specified: ::<empty>.` error).

Honestly, this is a bit of a nitpick, and it's not that big of a deal. I *can* take `EXPOSE 3000` out of the Dockerfile and just do `-p 3000` on the command line. I just like having it in the Dockerfile so it's on by default and I just have to turn it off in the few instances when I'll need it.

I also know that I *can* use a second Dockerfile that inherits from the first.

I'm just curious if it's possible to un-publish a port exposed in the Dockerfile when I do `docker run` (or possibly in docker-compose).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know that's not possible now. The best thing you can do is too use the `-P` option to map the 3000 to some random port, so it won't conflict with the main container instance, e.g.

```
docker run -it -P <some-image>
```

This will result in the following `docker ps`

```
main_container   0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp
run_container    0.0.0.0:32769->3000/tcp
```

Comment: Cool, yeah. re-mapping it still would cause issues. Thanks for the idea, though!

Comment: I'll accept this answer in a couple days if no-one else has a clever workaround. I also think the answer to whether or not one can 'un-expose/publish' a port is 'no' based on my testing and doc reading.

Answer (score 6):

Even a couple of years later, the situation hasn't changed much. There is no UNEXPOSE but atleast there is a workaround with "`docker save`" and "`docker load`" allowing to edit the metadata of a docker image. Atleast to remove volumes and ports, I have created a little script that can automate the task, see [docker-copyedit](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-copyedit).