# Is there a way to unexpose a port in Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, cloud, mosquitto

I am trying to deploy a mosquitto MQTT broker in our corporate cloud through docker image. The allowed ports that are exposed are in the range of 10000-10999.
By default eclipse-mosquitto image exposes port 1883. Is there a way to unexpose port 1883 and expose 10883?
This is my **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM eclipse-mosquitto:latest

COPY mosquitto.conf /mosquitto/config/
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh mosquitto-no-auth.conf /
EXPOSE 10883
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["/usr/sbin/mosquitto", "-c", "/mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf"]
```

Comment: Also see [If I use EXPOSE $PORT in a Dockerfile, can I un-expose the port it when I use `docker run`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33534363/if-i-use-expose-port-in-a-dockerfile-can-i-un-expose-the-port-it-when-i-use-d); on the one hand, you can't cancel or change `EXPOSE`, but on the other, it does almost nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Just because the container exposes port 1883 that doesn't mean that's the port you need to use access a running instance.

When you start the container using the `docker run` command you get to decide what port on the host machine is mapped to that port on the container.

E.g.

```
docker run -d -p 10883:1883 eclipse-mosquitto
```

This will expose port 10883 on the host and map it to 1883 on the container.

Answer (score 1):

"Expose" in dockerfile is kind of a meta data which tells which port you should work with. It does not open any port. So you can easily open any port you want.